# How to set custom configurations for embedded "Method-Draw" svg-edit fork

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-edit

How to use `setConfig` method with "Method Draw" editor.I tried setting them as below. But it doesn't support to set config options. But I was able to use `setSvgString`,`setResolution` methods as below.

My question is "how can I override default configurations by using `setConfig` method?"

```
var frame = document.getElementById('svgedit');
svgCanvas = new embedded_svg_edit(frame);
svgCanvas.setConfig({jGraduatePath: 'images/'});
```